# Random error on mutex lock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

A mutex lock succeeds or fails randomly, and fails with either :

```
Invalid argument
```

or

```
tpp.c:62: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= __sched_fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= __sched_fifo_max_prio)' failed.
```

The code is very basic as you can  see here :

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
main() {
  int ret;
  pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  ret = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("pthread_mutex_init\n");
    return 1;
  }
  ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("mutex_lock failed %s\n", strerror(ret));
    return 1;
  }
  ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("mutex_unlock failed %s\n", strerror(ret));
    return -1;
  }
```

Why is that ?

Comment: OT: It should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not initializing `attr`.  Its contents are undefined.

See [`pthread_mutexattr_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_init.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The function `pthread_mutexattr_init()` initialises a mutex attributes
>   object `attr` with the default value for all of the attributes defined
>   by the implementation.